# Unity3d black objects when tested in an Android phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

When I test my game in an actual android phone I get some objects colored in black. They are called LowpolyStreetPack and I have tried everything - changed the shader to different setting, added an animator component, added a mesh colider etc.

I have 4.7 version of Unity3d and I can't update it because my entire game is built with this version and then I have to fix other scripts.

Have this ever happened to you? What type of shader could be better?

Comment: +1 because I don't think this question is spam, it just needs more details: Are you using custom shaders or built in? Is the black pure black, or does it have a reflective quality? How do the assets look on a PC / Mac? Also, you should update to the latest version; it's worth the time tweaking code.

Comment: There is a difference when viewed on PC and on phone. On PC everything looks great, on Android phone they go black.

Answer (score 1):

What texture format are you using for the black objects? Black is a "default error color" in GLES, in particular for samplers which cannot be decoded (no data, or unsupported format). There are a number of proprietary texture formats in existence, which could well explain this one (e.g. if the assets were designed for iOS using PVRCT, and your Android phone GPU not from Img. Tech).

Comment: Here is a link to the unity asset - [link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/67475) , I have no idea what type of texture format is set as default, it just doesn't work on my phone when I test it. I am using Unity version 4.7 so it should have worked.